# How can I create a QTreeView like a folders and files view from database?

Tags: python-2.7, pyqt4, qtreeview, qtreewidgetitem

I'm using pyqt4 and I'm trying to create a QTreeView that contains albums and these contains pictures. They should be created by two arrays (they were created from oracle database)

```
album=[[1,'my life'],[2,'my job']]
picture=[[1,1,'My daugther'],[1,2,'my son'],[2,1,'my boss'],[2,2,'my jobmate']]
```

How can I load this data into a QTreeView? Or is better to use a QTreeWidget?

> My life
>   --My daughter
>   --my son
>   my job
>   --my boss
>   --my jobmate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved It. the code could be something like this:

```
model = QStandardItemModel(0,1)
self.treeMedia.setModel(model)
#codus is the id of the user albums and photos' owner
for rowalb in self.SELECT_TREE_ALBUM(codus):
#we create the album item
    nodeItem = QStandardItem(str(rowalb[1]).decode('utf-8'))
    for rowph in self.SELECT_TREE_PHOTO(int(rowalb[0])):
        #after that we create photos into an album
        childItem = QStandardItem(str(rowph[0]))
        childItem.setEditable(False)
        nodeItem.insertRows(0, [childItem])
    nodeItem.setEditable(False)
    model.appendRow(nodeItem)
#the name of the column
model.setHorizontalHeaderLabels(['Data'])
```

SELECT_TREE_ALBUM and SELECT_TREE_PHOTO are procedures that returns data from oracle database.